# Gray out a frame after clicking a radiobutton Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

i have this code, i'm trying to make the the first frame to gray out once the user click one of the choices so that the user cannot change to other choice. but when i run it, it already gray out the frame even before the user choose. i also want to make the second frame to be gray out until the user click/choose fro the first frame. can anyone help?

```
  from Tkinter import *
  def onclick():
     pass

  import tkMessageBox
  import ttk 

  root = Tk()

  root.title("Pantai Hospital")
  root.geometry("200x200")

  Label(root, text = "Welcome to Pantai Hospital!").grid()


  f1 = Frame(root, width = 350, height = 110) 

  f2 = Frame(f1, relief = GROOVE, borderwidth = 2)

  l9 = Label(f2, text = "Choose your specialist:")
  l9.grid()

  specialistchoose = IntVar()

  r1 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Cardiology", variable = specialistchoose, value = 1)
  r1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, stick = W) 

  r2 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Gastroenterology", variable = specialistchoose, value = 2)
  r2.grid(row = 1, column = 1,stick = W ) 

  r3 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Dermatology", variable = specialistchoose, value = 3)
  r3.grid (row = 1, column = 2,stick = W )

  r4 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Psychiatry", variable = specialistchoose, value = 4)
  r4.grid (row = 3, column = 0,stick = W )

  r5 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Dentist", variable = specialistchoose, value = 5)
  r5.grid(row = 3, column = 1,stick = W  )

  f2.place(relx = 0.01, rely = 0.125, anchor = NW)
  Label(f1, text = "Specialist").place(relx = .06, rely = 0.125, anchor = W)

  f1.grid()

  if specialistchoose.get() <> 'Cardiology' or 'Gastroenterology' or 'Dermatology' or 'Psychiatry' or 'Dentist' :
  for child in f2.winfo_children():
      child.configure(state = 'disable')

  f3 = Frame(root, width = 350, height = 110)
  f4 = Frame(f3, relief = GROOVE, borderwidth = 2)

  l15 = Label (f4, text = "Choose your preferred day:")
  l15.grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = W) 

  day = IntVar()

  cb1 = Checkbutton(f4, text = "Monday", variable = day, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
  cb1.grid(row = 4, column = 0,stick = W ) 
  cb2 = Checkbutton(f4, text = "Tuesday", variable = day, onvalue = 2, offvalue = 0)
  cb2.grid(row = 4, column = 1,stick = W ) 
  cb3 = Checkbutton(f4, text = "Wednesday", variable = day, onvalue = 3, offvalue = 0)
  cb3.grid(row = 4, column = 2, stick = W) 
  cb4 = Checkbutton(f4, text = "Thursday", variable = day, onvalue = 4, offvalue = 0)
  cb4.grid(row = 4, column = 3,stick = W ) 
  cb5 = Checkbutton (f4, text = "Friday", variable = day, onvalue = 5, offvalue = 0)
  cb5.grid(row = 5, column = 0, stick = W )
  cb6 = Checkbutton(f4, text = "Saturday", variable = day, onvalue = 6, offvalue = 0)
  cb6.grid(row = 5, column = 1, stick = W )
  cb7 = Checkbutton (f4, text = "Sunday", variable = day, onvalue = 7, offvalue = 0)
  cb7.grid(row = 5, column = 2, stick = W ) 

  f4.place(relx = 0.01, rely = 0.125, anchor = NW)
  Label(f3, text = "Day").place(relx = .06, rely = 0.125, anchor = W)

  f3.grid()
  root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your `if` statement evaluate `True` in any case. So it will disable the frame.
Try `specialistchoose.get() != 'Cardiology' or specialistchoose.get() != 'Gastroenterology' ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning the value of `specialistchoose.get()` is `0`, and the check for the buttons with an `if` is not dynamic.

The `Radiobutton` has a build in `command` which is evaluated every time the button is pressed. You can use that to deactivate the buttons.

Like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

def func():
    for child in f2.winfo_children():
        child.configure(state = 'disable')

import tkMessageBox
import ttk

root = Tk()

root.title("Pantai Hospital")
root.geometry("200x200")

Label(root, text = "Welcome to Pantai Hospital!").grid()


f1 = Frame(root, width = 350, height = 110)

f2 = Frame(f1, relief = GROOVE, borderwidth = 2)

l9 = Label(f2, text = "Choose your specialist:")
l9.grid()

specialistchoose = IntVar()

r1 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Cardiology", variable = specialistchoose, value = 1, command=func)
r1.grid(row = 1, column = 0, stick = W)

r2 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Gastroenterology", variable = specialistchoose, value = 2, command=func)
r2.grid(row = 1, column = 1,stick = W )

r3 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Dermatology", variable = specialistchoose, value = 3, command=func)
r3.grid (row = 1, column = 2,stick = W )

r4 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Psychiatry", variable = specialistchoose, value = 4, command=func)
r4.grid (row = 3, column = 0,stick = W )

r5 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Dentist", variable = specialistchoose, value = 5, command=func)
r5.grid(row = 3, column = 1,stick = W  )

f2.place(relx = 0.01, rely = 0.125, anchor = NW)
Label(f1, text = "Specialist").place(relx = .06, rely = 0.125, anchor = W)

f1.grid()



f3 = Frame(root, width = 350, height = 110)
f4 = Frame(f3, relief = GROOVE, borderwidth = 2)

l15 = Label (f4, text = "Choose your preferred day:")
l15.grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

day = IntVar()

cb1 = Checkbutton(f4, text = "Monday", variable = day, onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0)
cb1.grid(row = 4, column = 0,stick = W )
cb2 = Checkbutton(f4, text = "Tuesday", variable = day, onvalue = 2, offvalue = 0)
cb2.grid(row = 4, column = 1,stick = W )
cb3 = Checkbutton(f4, text = "Wednesday", variable = day, onvalue = 3, offvalue = 0)
cb3.grid(row = 4, column = 2, stick = W)
cb4 = Checkbutton(f4, text = "Thursday", variable = day, onvalue = 4, offvalue = 0)
cb4.grid(row = 4, column = 3,stick = W )
cb5 = Checkbutton (f4, text = "Friday", variable = day, onvalue = 5, offvalue = 0)
cb5.grid(row = 5, column = 0, stick = W )
cb6 = Checkbutton(f4, text = "Saturday", variable = day, onvalue = 6, offvalue = 0)
cb6.grid(row = 5, column = 1, stick = W )
cb7 = Checkbutton (f4, text = "Sunday", variable = day, onvalue = 7, offvalue = 0)
cb7.grid(row = 5, column = 2, stick = W )

f4.place(relx = 0.01, rely = 0.125, anchor = NW)
Label(f3, text = "Day").place(relx = .06, rely = 0.125, anchor = W)

f3.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

Side note to your code:

The `if` statement in your code always evaluates `True` in that case, as `'Cardiology' or 'Gastroenterology'` is `True`

You should use:

```
if specialistchoose.get() != 'Cardiology' or specialistchoose.get() != 'Gastroenterology' or specialistchoose.get() != 'Dermatology' or specialistchoose.get() != 'Psychiatry' or specialistchoose.get() != 'Dentist':
```