# Assign variable to radiobutton Tkinter

Tags: python, variables, tkinter

I have this code which asks user to select one of the choices. I used radiobuttons. After the user select his choice, the choice will be use another if statement. I already assigned the choice's variable as `variable = specialistchoose`. But when I use the `specialistchoose` or `specialistchoose.get()`, it does not work. Can anyone help?

```
                specialistchoose = IntVar()

                r1 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Cardiology", variable = specialistchoose, value = 1, command = command_r1 )
                r1.grid(row = 4, column = 0, stick = W) 

                r2 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Gastroenterology", variable = specialistchoose, value = 2, command =  command_r2)
                r2.grid(row = 4, column = 1,stick = W ) 

                r3 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Dermatology", variable = specialistchoose, value = 3, command = command_r3)
                r3.grid (row = 4, column = 2,stick = W )

                r4 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Psychiatry", variable = specialistchoose, value = 4, command = command_r4)
                r4.grid (row = 5, column = 0,stick = W )

                r5 = Radiobutton (f2, text = "Dentist", variable = specialistchoose, value = 5, command = command_r5)
                r5.grid(row = 5, column = 1,stick = W  )

                f2.place(relx = 0.01, rely = 0.125, anchor = NW)
                Label(f1, text = "Specialist").place(relx = .06, rely = 0.125, anchor = W)

                f1.grid(stick = W)

                if specialistchoose.get() == "Cardiology":
                    file = open ("test2.txt", "w")
                    file.write ("Specialist : Cardiology")
                    file.close()
                elif specialistchoose.get() == "Gastroenterology":
                    file = open ("test2.txt", "w")
                    file.write ("Specialist : Gastroenterology")
                    file.close()
                elif specialistchoose.get() == "Dermatology":
                    file = open ("test2.txt", "w")
                    file.write ("Specialist : Dermatology")
                    file.close()
                elif specialistchoose.get() == "Psychiatry":
                    file = open ("test2.txt", "w")
                    file.write("Specialist : Psychiatry")
                    file.close()
                elif specialistchoose.get() == "Dentist":
                    file = open ("test2.txt", "w")
                    file.write("Specialist : Dentist")
                    file.close()
```

note : this is just the sample of a longer code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are `get()`ting their values only right after they created, you'll get only their initial value and nothing more.

Try to get their value using `command`, or another button.

No idea what do you have under `command_rX`s but you should split those if's and put under respective `command`s.

Also, since your variables are `IntVar()` and you'll be getting `value` which will be between 1 and 5 inclusive since you assigned as such.

```
def command_r1():
    with open('test2.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write ("Specialist : Cardiology")

def command_r2():
    with open('test2.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write ("Specialist : Gastroenterology")
#etc...
```

or create a button, when that's clicked it'll get the value and does all those if-else things.

```
def external_button_callback():
    radioValue = specialistchoose.get()
    if radioValue == 1:
        with open('test2.txt', 'w') as file:
            file.write ("Specialist : Cardiology")
    #etc...

btn = Button(f2, text= "Get Value" command = external_button_callback)
btn.grid(row=6, column=0)
```

Another little thing is, when using files, it is better to use `with` statement since it handles closing automatically when you move out of scope and you don't need to worry about closing everytime.

And everytime you change value, that txt file will be created from scratch since you open it on `w` mode. I don't know if that's what you wanted or not but wanted to give a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `radiobutton` variable has nothing to do with its `text`. You declared the variable `specialistchoose` to be `IntVar` so it will be some int.

`if specialistchoose.get() == "Cardiology":` will never be `True`

Yesterday i answered your question on a very same topic here:[Gray out a frame after clicking a radiobutton Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154015/gray-out-a-frame-after-clicking-a-radiobutton-tkinter/35154535#35154535)

If you alter the `func` to something like this:

```
def func():
    print specialistchoose.get()
```

You will be able to see what values each `radiobutton` gets when it is pressed.

From there you can make a condition if they are pressed or not.